# VBA Excel - How do i convert Date Strings from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I'm new to this... I'm having problems converting date strings in Excel. Can anybody help me?

Instead of converting, I'm getting something like this:   -/2-13/06/2017

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub muda_datas()
    For linha = 3 To 479
    MsgBox Cells(linha, 24).Value
        dia = Cells(linha, 24).Value
        mes = Mid(Cells(linha, 24).Value, 6, 2)
        Cells(linha, 24).Value = ano & "-" & mes & "-" & dia
    Next linha
End Sub
```

Comment: You never declare `ano`, so so that's why you always have `-` at the start.  Can you provide an example of the input?

Comment: Does this not do what you want? `format("01/12/2019","yyyy-mm-dd")`

Comment: If @Nathan_Sav's suggestion doesn't work, then include a `CDate` to explicitly convert Text to Date:  `Cells(linha, 24).Value = Format(CDate(Cells(linha, 24).Value),"yyyy-mm-dd")`

Comment: Is `Cells(....).Value` giving you a `Date` or a `String`?

Comment: I think that you have made a mistake trying to extract ano variable from the string you extract date parts.could you post the whole string?